# Magickartenmarkt RESTful API don't work

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to authenticate my account with Magickartenmarkt RESTful API.

Below is a link of above mentioned API. https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API_2.0:Main_Page

My code is as below:

```
<?php

$method             = "GET";
$url                = "https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/v2.0/account";
$appToken           = "My App token"; //double checked in my account
$appSecret          = "My App secret"; //double checked in my account
$accessToken        = "My Access token"; //double checked in my account
$accessSecret       = "My Access token secret"; //double checked in my account
$nonce              = uniqid();
$timestamp          = time();
$signatureMethod    = "HMAC-SHA1";
$version            = "2.0";

/**
* Gather all parameters that need to be included in the Authorization header and are know yet
*
* @var $params array|string[] Associative array of all needed authorization header parameters
*/
$params             = array(
   'realm'                     => $url,
   'oauth_consumer_key'        => $appToken,
   'oauth_token'               => $accessToken,
   'oauth_nonce'               => $nonce,
   'oauth_timestamp'           => $timestamp,
   'oauth_signature_method'    => $signatureMethod,
   'oauth_version'             => $version,
);

/**
* Start composing the base string from the method and request URI
*
* @var $baseString string Finally the encoded base string for that request, that needs to be signed
*/
$baseString         = strtoupper($method) . "&";
$baseString        .= rawurlencode($url) . "&";

/*
* Gather, encode, and sort the base string parameters
*/
$encodedParams      = array();
foreach ($params as $key => $value)
{
   if ("realm" != $key)
   {
       $encodedParams[rawurlencode($key)] = rawurlencode($value);
   }
}
ksort($encodedParams);

/*
* Expand the base string by the encoded parameter=value pairs
*/
$values             = array();
foreach ($encodedParams as $key => $value)
{
   $values[] = $key . "=" . $value;
}
$paramsString       = rawurlencode(implode("&", $values));
$baseString        .= $paramsString;

/*
* Create the signingKey
*/
$signatureKey       = rawurlencode($appSecret) . "&" . rawurlencode($accessSecret);

/**
* Create the OAuth signature
* Attention: Make sure to provide the binary data to the Base64 encoder
*
* @var $oAuthSignature string OAuth signature value
*/
$rawSignature       = hash_hmac("sha1", $baseString, $signatureKey, true);
$oAuthSignature     = base64_encode($rawSignature);

/*
* Include the OAuth signature parameter in the header parameters array
*/
$params['oauth_signature'] = $oAuthSignature;

/*
* Construct the header string
*/
$header             = "Authorization: OAuth ";
$headerParams       = array();
foreach ($params as $key => $value)
{
   $headerParams[] = $key . "=\"" . $value . "\"";
}
$header            .= implode(", ", $headerParams);


/*Initialisation de la ressource curl*/
$curlHandle = curl_init();

/*
* Set the required cURL options to successfully fire a request to MKM's API
*
* For more information about cURL options refer to PHP's cURL manual:
* http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
*/
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

/**
* Execute the request, retrieve information about the request and response, and close the connection
*
* @var $content string Response to the request
* @var $info array Array with information about the last request on the $curlHandle
*/
$content            = curl_exec($curlHandle);
$info               = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);
curl_close($curlHandle);

/*
* Convert the response string into an object
*
* If you have chosen XML as response format (which is standard) use simplexml_load_string
* If you have chosen JSON as response format use json_decode
*
* @var $decoded \SimpleXMLElement|\stdClass Converted Object (XML|JSON)
*/
// $decoded            = json_decode($content);
$decoded            = simplexml_load_string($content);

var_dump($content);
?>
```

The var_dump return

> Resource not found. error-router-no-match

This code can be found here :https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_libcurl

I tried to GET google webpage and it worked fine so i don't think it's cURL problem.

I'm not sure this API works. Need some help to be sure about that. Is it the API or my code ?

Answer (score 0):

The info on https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API_Main_Page states that the Api 2.0 is not yet live. Only the documentation for it is.